# Magento discount labels - getting special price on category page

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to create discount badges on category pages in Magento - I have already done it on product pages, but i'm havig trouble getting it to display the right amount of discount on category pages

This is what i used to call it on product page:

```
    <span class="price1" style="text-decoration:none;">     
<?php $specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice(); 
             if ($specialprice){?>
             <?php if ($specialprice != $_regularPrice){?>
<?php $special_percent = round(100 - (( 100/$_regularPrice ) * $_finalPrice ), 0);?>
    <?php if($special_percent != 0) echo $special_percent.'%'; ?>
</span>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Since the category page calls the entire price block only with

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

... i don't know how to edit anything in without it affecting the product page price block. Can i just change the way i define $specialprice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\products\list.html`, put the following under `<div class="product-image">`

```
<?php if ( ($_product->getFinalPrice() - $_product->getPrice()) < 0) { ?>
<img class="discount-badge" src="<php? echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/discount_badge.png'); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Of course, you should customize as you wish, I just gave you a hint.

Comment: Thanks, was very simple and worked great, went a step further and put in percentages of discount in each one